# Two surf plots on one figure

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d, matlab-figure

I want to plot on top of one surf graph another surf graph. This is the code.

```
x1=0:0.01:1;
y1=0:0.01:1;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x1,y1);

Z=(X.*Y)./(X+Y-(X.*Y));

surf(X,Y,Z)
hold on;
[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z1=(X1.*Y1)./(X1+Y1-(X1.*Y1));

surf(X1,Y1,Z1,'FaceColor', 'black','EdgeColor','none');
```

And in the graph I get how can I make the `surf(X1,Y1,Z1,'FaceColor', 'black','EdgeColor','none');` more visible. In working with plots there's the option to change marker size and marker type. Is there are a similar thing for surf graph?

In the graph below I want to make the circled area more visible. Is there a way like to increase the marker size in surf graphs? Or to reduce the colour of the first surf plot a bit.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show/highlight?

Comment: @Suever  I want to highltight the area from the surf plot `[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z1=(X1.*Y1)./(X1+Y1-(X1.*Y1));

surf(X1,Y1,Z1,'FaceColor', 'black','EdgeColor','none');` Here `x,y` are a subset of `x1,y1`. I want to highlight the area circled in the above graph. If I can make the other surf plot less visible that would be okay as well

Comment: You could set `FaceAlpha` of the first surface to something like 0.5 which will make it more transparent?